# eBatNS - GetMyeBaySelling.php returns nothing

Tags: php, ebay-api

I want to track my eBay activity with eBatNS and most functions I need work very well. However, I like to get all my active listings (hopefully) with GetMyeBaySelling.php - but it returns only:

```
---------------------
Object Dump:
GetMyeBaySellingResponseType Object
(
[Timestamp:protected] => 2015-01-25 03:39:15
[Ack:protected] => Success
[Version:protected] => 905
[Build:protected] => E905_CORE_APISELLING_17350212_R1
)
```

The requesting PHP is:

```
<?php
/**
* sources
*/
require_once 'setincludepath.php';
'GetSellerListRequestType.php';
'EbatNs_Environment.php';
/**
* sample_GetSellerList
 * 
 * Sample call for GetSellerList
 * 
 * @package ebatns
 * @subpackage samples_trading
 * @author johann 
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2008
 * @version $Id: sample_GetSellerList.php,v 1.107 2012-09-10 11:01:21
michaelcoslar Exp $
* @access public
*/
class sample_GetSellerList extends EbatNs_Environment
{
/**
 * sample_GetSellerList::dispatchCall()
 * 
 * Dispatch the call
 *
 * @param array $params array of parameters for the eBay API call
 * 
 * @return boolean success
 */
public function dispatchCall ($params)
{
    $req = new GetSellerListRequestType();

    $res = $this->proxy->GetSellerList($req);
    if ($this->testValid($res))
    {
        $this->dumpObject($res);
        return (true);
    }
    else 
    {

      return (false);
    }
}
}
$x = new sample_GetSellerList();
$x->dispatchCall(array());
?>
```

I hope somebody can point me in the right direction. In the worst case I do have a working HTTP request that can do the job too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using and older version of EbatNS. To be sure not to use a version that isn't supported by eBay anymore please first download the most recent version from our new [EbatNS](https://sdk.intradesys.com/ebay_api_sdk_online_generator) download page.

The call that you are looking for is the GetMyeBaySelling call from the Trading API. Here is a sample code how to use EbatNS for this call:

```
require_once 'EbatNs_Session.php';
require_once 'EbatNs_ServiceProxy.php';
require_once 'EbatNs_Session.php';
require_once 'EbatNs_DataConverter.php';

$session = new EbatNs_Session();
$session->setSiteId(0);
$session->setUseHttpCompression(1);
$session->setAppMode(0);
$session->setDevId('YOUR_DEV_ID_HERE');
$session->setAppId('YOUR_APP_ID_HERE');
$session->setCertId('YOUR_CERT_ID_HERE');
$session->setRequestToken('YOUR_TOKEN_HERE');
$session->setTokenUsePickupFile(false);
$session->setTokenMode(true);

require_once 'EbatNs_ServiceProxy.php';
$proxy = new EbatNs_ServiceProxy($session, 'EbatNs_DataConverterUtf8');

require_once 'GetMyeBaySellingRequestType.php';
$getmyebaysellingrequest = new GetMyeBaySellingRequestType();
$itemlistcustomization = new ItemListCustomizationType();
$getmyebaysellingrequest->setActiveList($itemlistcustomization);
$itemlistcustomization->setInclude("true");
$getmyebaysellingrequest->setVersion("903");

$response = $proxy->GetMyeBaySelling($getmyebaysellingrequest);
```

There is also a playground available where you can customize and test all calls of the Trading API. I've created an example for you [here](https://sdk.intradesys.com/s/98dce83da57b0395e163467c9dae521b). You just need to login and execute the call to get all your active listings. Once you have adapted the call to your needs you can click on "Retrieve PHP code" to get a ready-to-use code snipplet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the meantime I made myself familiar with the direct API calls using XML and so far it works fine for me.